# How to read nested dictionary from CSV file for the given file structure?

Tags: python, dictionary

I am new to python and stackoverflow. Please be kind. I have a csv file that looks like this:

```
Material,Property,Temperature,Allowable
EBM,Proof Strength,10,100
EBM,Proof Strength,100,50
EBM,Ultimate Strength,10,200
EBM,Ultimate Strength,120,100
TAK,Proof Strength,20,120
TAK,Proof Strength,150,70
TAK,Ultimate Strength,20,230
TAK,Ultimate Strength,100,130
```

I need an output like this:

```
    mat_database = {'TAK':{'Proof Strength':{'Temperature':['C', 20.0, 150.0],  'Allowable':['MPa',120.0, 70.0]},
'Ultimate Strength':{'Temperature':['C', 20.0, 100.0],  'Allowable':['MPa',230.0, 130.0]}},
'EBM':{'Proof Strength':{'Temperature':['C', 10.0, 100.0],  'Allowable':['MPa',100.0, 50.0]},
'Ultimate Strength':{'Temperature':['C', 10.0, 120.0],  'Allowable':['MPa',200.0, 100.0]}}}
```

I am able to read the csv file using DictReader as shown below:

```
import os
import csv
SourceDir = ExtAPI.ExtensionManager.CurrentExtension.InstallDir  #Source directory got from Ansys application
    csvfile = "Material_Database.csv"
    fs = os.path.join(SourceDir, csvfile)
    ExtAPI.Log.WriteMessage(str(fs))
    mat_database = {}
    with open(fs, mode = 'r') as csv_file:
        data = csv.DictReader(csv_file, delimiter=",")
        for row in data:
            #code
            
            
    print mat_database
```

I tried several nesting method found online. None suits my purpose or I am missing something. Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: Your desired output is not valid Python.

Comment: How do you get the units (MPa, C)? Do you just put them in by hand?

Comment: Thanks Mark, There are some missing braces in output of my original post which I have corrected now.

Comment: Yes, in the Temperature and Allowable lists I always need first entry to be 'C' and 'MPa' respectively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
d = {}
header = True
with open("txt.csv") as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        if header:
            header = False
            continue
        m, p, t, a = line.strip().split(",")
        d_m = d.get(m,{})
        d_p = d_m.get(p, {})
        d_t = d_p.get('Temperature',['C'])
        d_t.append(float(t))
        d_a = d_p.get('Allowable',['MPa'])
        d_a.append(float(a))
        d_p['Temperature'] = d_t
        d_p['Allowable'] = d_a
        d_m[p] = d_p
        d[m] = d_m
print(d)
```